# How to handle Cross-Origin Resource Sharing in a production level appliaction of angular 6?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, httprequest, angular6

i know i can allow any request come to the server by modifying the server to add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. but is it safe do this in production level. or is there any other secuared way to do this ?

Comment: CORS can be handled on server side by allowing request from white-listed domains. Which backend are you using by the way?

Comment: i am using spring boot.

Comment: you can check the answer for spring boot

Comment: ok, Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explaining CORS.

For every XHR(XMLHttpRequest) request, browser sends a pre-flight request to the server with appropriate headers to check whether the actual request is allowed by the server or not. If you will not add any handler then it will throw an exception on the browser.

To handle this in Spring boot, you can add following annotation on the Controller methods or class (to make it global) to handle requests :-

```
     @CrossOrigin(
        origins = { "*" },     // You can add your allowed origins here
        methods = { RequestMethod.GET },   // Request Method
        allowCredentials = "true",
        allowedHeaders = CorsConfiguration.ALL,   // Allowed Headers
        exposedHeaders = {})    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greeting(@RequestBody SomeClass
     name) {
        // your own code
    }
```

You can also check [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) for reference

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you just make a whitelist of hosts to be allowed, if you are using `express` this can be the following code.

```
const cors = require('cors');

const whitelist = [
  'https://myfrontserver1.com',
  'https://myfrontserver2.com',
  'https://myfrontserver3.com',
]; // the white list could be extracted from database, or a config file is up to you

app.use(cors({ origin: whitelist, credentials: true }));
```

Comment: it worked in expressjs. Thank you!. do you know how this works in spring boot?

Comment: Not a java dev sorry :(

Comment: @LasithaNarangoda This answer doesn't solves the actual problem for spring boot. So, this should not be an excepted answer for the question.